# Return Neo4j cypher query result as variable in global scope with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j server running on docker.
I'm trying to execute some query to this server using plain javascript, running inside an html file.  What I'd like to obtain is to use the query result in a global variable.
With this variable, I would like to update some

`<select>`
option inside html.
The returned query value looks like this:

```json
{
    "type_A" : {
        "Sub Assembly" : [
            [ "B.1", "descrizione per B.1", 0 ],
            [ "B.2", "descrizione per B.2", 1 ],
            [ "B.3", "descrizione per B.3", 2 ]
        ],
        "Component" : [
            [ "B.1.1", "descrizione per B.1.1", 3 ],
            [ "B.2.1.1", "descrizione per B.2.1.1", 6 ]
        ],
        "Assembly" : [
            [ "A", "descrizione per A", 12 ],
            [ "B", "descrizione per B", 26 ]
        ]
    },
    "type_B" : {
        "Sub Assembly" : [
            [ "C.1", "descrizione per C.1", 8 ],
            [ "C.2", "descrizione per C.2", 9 ],
            [ "C.3", "descrizione per C.3", 10 ]
        ],
        "Assembly" : [
            [ "C", "descrizione per C", 7 ]
        ]
    }
}
```

The first `<select>` will have type_A and type_B as options, the second will have for example Sub Assembly, Assembly, Component (if I choose type_A in the first select). Based on the choices done, I'll fill a list with the corresponding array content.
I was able to execute the query, but now I'm stuck on how to use the query response.

What I have tried is (the query is an example, not the one I use)

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // define our fetch functions, and handle our async promises
        const driver = neo4j.driver('locahost', neo4j.auth.basic('user', 'password'))
        const session = driver.session()

        async function getNodes() {
            session
                .run('MATCH (n) RETURN n.code AS code')
                .then(results => {
                    const output = []
                    results.records.forEach(res => {
                        output.push(res.get('code'))
                    })
                    console.log(output)
                    return output
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error;
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    session.close();
                });
        }


        var out = getNodes().then(res => {
            return res
        })
        console.log(out)

    </script>
```

As console.log I get

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]:Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

I thought to use a global variable so I need only one request to the server to get all the preliminary information needed to "prepare" the DOM, and manage the two `<select>` change event.

Is this a correct way to manage the "problem"?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this code right here:

```
        async function getNodes() {
            session
                .run('MATCH (n) RETURN n.code AS code')
                .then(results => {
                    const output = []
                    results.records.forEach(res => {
                        output.push(res.get('code'))
                    })
                    console.log(output)
                    return output
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    throw error;
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    session.close();
                });
        }
```

Your function getNodes() returns *nothing*.   There are returns inside of the nested promises, but the actual function returns nothing.  You might want to put a "return" before "session"